# how to check all index of table using javavscript in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

i have created a table in magento with two column id and zip_code. but only [0] index value is fetching. how to fetch value of all index. i am using this code

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function custom_save(){


         zipcode = document.getElementById('billing:postcode').value;
         //alert(zipcode);
        if (zipcode == <?php echo $cus_zip_code[0]['zip_code']; ?>) {
             //alert('We will deliver within 2-3 days');
             document.getElementById('d').innerHTML = 'We will deliver within 2-3 days!';
             billing.save();
        } else {
            //alert('We will deliver after 10 days');
            document.getElementById('d').innerHTML = 'We will deliver after 10 days!';
            billing.save();
        }
    }
    </script>
<?php 
        $connection = Mage::getModel('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `custom_zip_code`';
        $cus_zip_code = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
        //print_r($cus_zip_code);
        foreach($cus_zip_code as $zipvalue){

        $cust_zip = $zipvalue['zip_code'];
        //echo '<pre>';
        //print_r($cust_zip);
        }

?>
```

Comment: when am i entering value of index [0] it is working fine. but its not working for value of index [1], [2]......etc. what should i do anyone can help me.

Comment: please provide your collection

Comment: @murtuza how? and where please tell me

Comment: i am using this code for select table and fetching data from table. table data are showing in frontend with print_r   <?php 
  $connection = Mage::getModel('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `custom_zip_code`';
  $cus_zip_code = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
  //print_r($cus_zip_code);
  foreach($cus_zip_code as $zipvalue){
   
  $cust_zip = $zipvalue['zip_code'];
  //echo '<pre>';
  //print_r($cust_zip);
  }
  
?>